# Xcode 4 color themes are not working in xcode 4.4.1

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I wanted to try a new color theme for xcode so i downloaded and installed the once that are made for xcode 4.  When i go to preferences and click on any one of the once i installed it just shows a default theme.  Are they not compatible?

Comment: I edited out the last part of your question since it makes your question ["subjective"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). The rest of the question I believe is fine, and it would be a shame if the question was closed as Not Constructive just for that last bit.

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't sure if this question would be appropriate here all together. I guess the first part is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got a .xccolortheme theme file, you'll need to convert it to a .dvtcolortheme.

You can easily convert it using this ruby script: http://digitalflapjack.com/blog/2011/jan/24/xcodedpthemes/

I recently used this script to convert the Morrowind theme at: http://www.natestedman.com/post/morrowind-for-textmate-xcode/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Xcode 4.4.1 uses a different format for custom color themes (.dvtcolortheme).

However it is just a plist with (a little bit) different tags, so I was able to export my old preferences (.xccolortheme) by simply opening both files with TextEdit and modifying manually the colors copying the values I got from the old .xccolortheme file. Notice that the colors in .dvtcolortheme format have 4 values (RGBA) instead of the 3 of .xccolortheme. To get the right value simply use 1 as alpha.

.dvtcolortheme has besides some tags that are not in .xccolortheme. For those colors...well, set the one you prefer (it's probably better to use Xcode for that, since this way you'll also get a preview).